# SQL After Update Trigger

Tags: mysql

Im having some trouble with sql triggers in MySQL. The tables below are just used for testing.

First table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`t1` (
  `c1` INT NOT NULL,
  `c2` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `c3` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`c1`));
```

Second Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `test`.`t2` (
  `cc1` INT NOT NULL,
  `cc2` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  `cc3` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`cc1`));
```

`cc1` references `c1`

ALl i want to do is, if the values in c2 are updated, then the corresponding field should be updated in cc2.
The trigger i came up with is:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `test`.`t1_AFTER_UPDATE`; 

DELIMITER $$

USE `test`$$

CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `test`.`t1_AFTER_UPDATE` AFTER UPDATE ON `t1` FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN
     update t2

     set cc2=c2

     where t2.cc1=t1.c1;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

This executes with no errors but if i try to update the values of c2,

```
UPDATE `test`.`t1` SET `c2` = '23' WHERE (`c1` = '11');
```

> Operation failed: There was an error while applying the SQL script to
>   the database. ERROR 1054: 1054: Unknown column 't1.c1' in 'where
>   clause'

The update goes through if i remove the trigger.

Comment: in triggers you can use the `old` and `new ` keywords to get access to the triggers table data in this case `t1` table depening on trigger event type like (ALTER UPDATE, or AFTER INSERT).. i believe it should be `where t2.cc1=old.t1.c1;` instead to make it make it work try it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a Trigger, we refer to columns in the rows being updated/inserted/deleted by `NEW` (after operation), and `OLD` (before operation) keywords.

You will need to use these keywords in order to be able to update the other table.

Also, we can optimize the Trigger to initiate `UPDATE` operation only when there has been a change observed in the `c2` value.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `test`.`t1_AFTER_UPDATE`; 
DELIMITER $$
USE `test`$$

CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `test`.`t1_AFTER_UPDATE` 
AFTER UPDATE ON `t1` FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

  -- Check if there has been any change in the c2 value or not
  IF (NEW.c2 <> OLD.c2) THEN 

      -- Update only when there is some change 
      UPDATE t2
      SET cc2 = NEW.c2  -- access the recent updated value of c2 using NEW keyword
      WHERE cc1 = NEW.c1;  -- access the c1 value of updated row using NEW keyword
  END IF;

END$$

DELIMITER ;
```